# Avoid registering every single service with dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have got an application that has a lot of services registered via DI, I was wondering if there's a best way of registering that in this way

```
      services.AddScoped<IDestinationService, DestinationService>();
        services.AddScoped<IAttractionService, AttractionService>();
        services.AddScoped<ICartService, CartService>();
        services.AddScoped<IPersonalService, PersonalService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEncryptionHelper, EncryptionHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<IAddressService, AddressService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRegistrationService, UserRegistrationService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRoleService, UserRoleService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRolesService, UserRolesService>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductAvailabilityService, ProductAvailabilityService>();
```

I thought of creating an attribute and putting it in the class but I don't know if it's a good practice.. any suggestions?

Comment: Personally I think that's perfectly fine. It's readable and it's the first place a developer would look if they need information on DI services.

Comment: yes but now we've 32 services and growing... need to reduce such boilderplate

Comment: What you're looking for is a technique called Batch-Registration or Auto-Registration. It's something that's not supported OOTB with the MS.DI container. You can either build this yourself using reflection, you can use an extension on top of MS.DI -such as Scrutor- to do this for you, or you upgrade to a full fledged DI container that supports this OOTB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think an attribute to mark classes to be registered by DI container is a good solution. It's what I do in my own projects.

I've created an attribute like so:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Class,
    AllowMultiple = false,
    Inherited = true)]
public sealed class DiClassAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServiceLifetime Lifetime { get; internal set; }

    public DiClassAttribute(
        ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
    {
        Lifetime = lifetime;
    }
}
```

Which I then use to mark my DI services like so (I use an abstract base class to not have to add the attribute to *every* class):

```
[DiClass]
public abstract class BaseService
{
    // Rest of class...
}
```

And I've defined a custom extension method for `IServiceCollection` to automatically add all the marked classes to DI container:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomServices(
        this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var types = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract
                && t.GetCustomAttribute<DiClassAttribute>() != null)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<DiClassAttribute>()!;
            var lifetime = attribute.Lifetime;

            var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

            foreach (var i in interfaces)
            {
                services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(i, type, lifetime));
            }

            if (!interfaces.Any())
            {
                services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(type, type, lifetime));
            }
        }

        return services;
    }
```

Which I call like so in my `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddCustomServices();
```

Has worked very well for me.

Comment: We did the same, but we used a generic interface `IRegisterServiceAs<>`. So at the class we wrote `public class MyService : IMyService, IRegisterServiceAs<IMyService>`.

Comment: Biggest problem in that case, you have to ensure that alle assemblies are loaded into the load context, before you can find your types via reflection. So either you have to _touch_ at least one type in each assembly before calling this extension method or you have to iterate through the working folder and try to load all .dll files with `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(filename)` beforehand.

Comment: they're all in the same assembly

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a marker interface, e.g. `IService` so that I can collect all the implementing types with their specific interface.

```cs
// marker interface
public interface IService { }

public interface ISomeService : IService { }
public interface IAnyService : IService { }
public interface INoService : IService { }

public class SomeService : ISomeService { }
public class AnyService : IAnyService { }
public class NoService : INoService { }

// Although I use Autofac the concept is the same in MS DI
public class DependencyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            // ThisAssembly is built-in property
            // for the current executing assembly.
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
            // Filter IService marker interface implementations
            .Where(
                type =>
                !type.IsAbstract
                &&
                typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            )
            // Determine the service type
            // E.g. for NoService the service type will be INoService.
            .As(
                implementationType =>
                implementationType.GetInterfaces().Single(
                    serviceType => serviceType.Name == $"I{implementationType.Name}"
                )
            )
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```